# ReactJS pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I'm trying pagination in ReactJS.
We have only horizontal pagination now using `npm install react-js-pagination`

I want to achieve pagination on both row level(horizontal) and column(vertical) level.
[image: Pagination]

As you see the image the x-axis pagination control will navigate the user horizontally and Y-axis for vertically
Is there any way to achieve this in ReactJS or any NPM package is available ?

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding the concept of pagination (or I have been misunderstanding it for a very long time; that is a possibility too). Pagination is about splitting your data into "chunks" that can be presented in a sequence, regardless of how you are going to actually render them in your layout; the ideas of "rows", "columns", "horizontal" and "vertical" are something concerning your layout, not the pagination of your data... or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add some class names to the `Pagination` component and then style with `css` in order to display them vertically.

For example you could do something like this:

1. Add `itemClass="page-item" linkClass="page-link"` to `Pagination` component
2. Inside one of your css file add the following style blocks:

`.pagination { display: inline-block; }` and
`.page-item { transform: rotate(90deg); }`

This way you should have something very similar to what you show in your image. From there you could build up the rest depending on your project.

Comment: I do not think the issue is how to display the pagination links horizontally o vertically; the question is: what is it supposed to happen when you select, say, `2` (horizontal) and `5` (vertical)? Which "chunk" of data will be displayed?

Comment: Marco Nisi and secan , Thanks for your answers. 
Hi @secan, you are right about pagination and my doubt here is whether I will able to implement pagination on both column and row level simultaneously as displayed in the screenshot.

Comment: Tony ok, but still I don't understand what should be the result of that logic. If you answer the @secan question maybe we could help you.